# AWS Cognito - Authorized uploads/downloads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, bucket

I am developing an app where signed-in users can upload/download files. I can't really figure out how to restrict users that are not registered. I have been reading about AWS Cognito and Identity Pools and so on but still don't know how to sign user in to give permissions to upload/download.

I am using a simple custom api for login/register. Should I use OAuth or something to achieve what I need?

There is not many guides to make it work or maybe I can't really understand the concept of Cognito or Bucket.

I started coding 3 months ago so I am not really experienced. I appreciate if you can give me an idea.

Comment: Have you been referring Upload/Download on S3?

Comment: I need signed-in users to be able to upload/download files through CloudFront. I am not sure if it is wise to use Cognito to achieve this or I can simply check authorization in the backend. I need a suggestion for a pratical solution. Which one would you pick?

Comment: I don't think so Cloud Front will be used here as its mainly used for CDN (web content distribution). Anyways, You may upload/download file to S3, where optionally you can use S3-Transfer acceleration which internally uses cloud front.

Comment: I am not really experienced since I started coding 3 months ago but I am not sure using CDN for user uploads/downloads is a bad practice. I have seen so many websites that serve user-uploaded files. If files need to be served faster globally, isn't that what CDN is used for?

Comment: To correct myself, yes, CloudFront can also be used where users are globally distributed. Could see answered into FAQ ,  Q:  How should I choose between S3 Transfer Acceleration and Amazon CloudFront’s PUT/POST? ->
S3 Transfer Acceleration optimizes the TCP protocol and adds additional intelligence between the client and the S3 bucket, making S3 Transfer Acceleration a better choice if a higher throughput is desired. If you have objects that are smaller than 1GB or if the data set is less than 1GB in size, you should consider using Amazon CloudFront's PUT/POST commands for optimal performance